# SwiftUI @ViewBuilder, how to return `some Shape` instead of a more generic `some View`?

Tags: swiftui, shapes, swift-protocols

Consider the following scenario: You defined some custom shapes, say for instance `LoggedInShape, NoAuthShape, AdminShape`, all of them conforming to a user-defined protocol, for example:

```
protocol HasNormalizedAABB: Shape {
    func normalizedAABB() -> CGRect
}
```

Now, somewhere else you have an enum like this:

```
enum AuthStatus {
   case .loggedIn
   case .noAuth
   case .admin
}
```

The objective is to return a different shape based on the auth status of the user, and then apply to it a styling that's the same for each of those. You could do something like this:

```
@ViewBuilder
func ShapeFor(status: AuthStatus) -> some View {
    switch status {
        case .loggedIn:
            LoggedInShape()

        case .noAuth:
            NoAuthShape()

        case .admin:
            AdminShape()
    }
}
```

Then apply whatever styling to the shape, like filling it or stroking a border, like this:

```
ShapeFor(status: currentAuthStatus)
    .fill(.red)
```

Doing so will result in an error complaining that `.fill` is not defined on `View`, and rightly so since it's defined on `Shape`. Let's try to swap `some View` for `some Shape`. This is what I get: `_ConditionalView<LoggedInShape, _ConditionalView<NoAuthShape, AdminShape>>` does not conform to `Shape`.

My temporary solution is to apply the styling to each shape individually inside the `switch`, but I don't want to keep it, since

1. I'll need to do the same thing but with different styling somewhere else in the app, and if I do so, I'll have to define a new function each time the styling has to change
2. If I want to change one thing, I have to do this once for each member of the enum (that in my case in more than the three of this example).

Comment: Since you can't return `some Shape`, you're a little stuck. You can, however, create a modifier function (just like `fill`) that does all of your styling as an extension on `Shape` -- you'll still have to put it in each case of the `switch`, though

Comment: @jnpdx: That's what I'd have done if I needed to use it with just a single set of modifiers. Unfortunately I need to use this in multiple places with different styles. I was even thinking about making `ShapeFor` accept an additional parameter of type `ViewModifier`, even though I'm unsure whether or not it's a good idea.

Comment: Solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733685?login=true)